# HTML/CSS - how to position an image in the above the right and left corner of a panel

Tags: html, css

Hello I have some issues to make elements to position themselves just above a panel.

Here is what I have at the moment:
https://jsfiddle.net/tn8b82u9/11/

```css
.main_container {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#logo_2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main_container">
  <div id="logo_1">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/t/55fc06a8e4b043168701253c/1466862019287/?format=1000w" />
  </div>
  <div id="logo_2">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/t/55fc06a8e4b043168701253c/1466862019287/?format=1000w" />
  </div>
  <div id="notice" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="user_form" class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Notice</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">Hello there !</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

What I want is the first black box should be just above the left corner of the panel and the second black box in the right corner of the panel. Here is an image to make things clear:

[image]

Comment: Container and child containers are your friends here... they will make also resposive your page

Comment: Is this a modal pop-up type of thing? There are probably 10 ways to do this, depending on what you want to happen / and the context.

Comment: Your example should get broken down to a generalized state like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/kekcykq6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit:
>
> Cleaned css from [@drew-kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4204026/drew-kennedy)
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/tn8b82u9/14/

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="row top-logos">
      <div class="col-lg-12 clear">
      <div id="logo_1">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/t/55fc06a8e4b043168701253c/1466862019287/?format=1000w" />
  </div>
  <div id="logo_2">
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/t/55fc06a8e4b043168701253c/1466862019287/?format=1000w" />
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="notice" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="user_form" class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Notice</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            Hello there !
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

CSS:

```
.main_container {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo_1 {
  float: right;
}

#logo_2 {
  float: left;
}

.clear:before, .clear:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.top-logos{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tn8b82u9/13/

Comment: Cleaned up your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tn8b82u9/14/). Almost all of the css didn't do anything or Bootstrap already provided out of the box.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Nice, I'm not using bootstrap.

Comment: Nah but the OP is, so might as well use the classes provided. :)